# MVC4 Pass custom view Model back to Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a custom class

```
public class BloggerViewModel
{        
    public Person Blogger;
    public List<BloggerWebsite> BloggerWebsites;
}
```

That I pass into a view

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        blogger = GetById(id);            
        var WebSites = GetBloggersWebsites(Id);            
        var BloggerViewModel = new BloggerViewModel();
        BloggerViewModel.Blogger = blogger;
        BloggerViewModel.BloggerWebsites = WebSites;
        return View(BloggerViewModel);
    }
```

Then when I post back to the edit action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(BloggerViewModel entity)
{
    return View(entity);
}
```

`entity` is null.

My view is something like this ( I took out allot of the code that you didn't need to see. Such as most of the text box bindings)

```
@model Bloginect.Model.Models.BloggerViewModel

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Person</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Blogger.Id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Blogger.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Blogger.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Blogger.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Blogger.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Blogger.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Blogger.LastName)
    </div>

        <div class="editor-field">

            @if (Model.BloggerWebsites[0].Website != null)
            {
                Html.EditorFor(model => model.BloggerWebsites[0].Website);
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBox("Website1")
            }

        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @if (Model.BloggerWebsites[1].Website != null)
            {
                Html.EditorFor(model => model.BloggerWebsites[0].Website);
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBox("Website2")
            }
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @if (Model.BloggerWebsites[2].Website != null)
            {
                Html.EditorFor(model => model.BloggerWebsites[0].Website);
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.TextBox("Website3")
            }          
        </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I have checked out some of the other replies to similar questions on this and they did not answer my question.

Comment: You're rendering `Html.EditorFor(model => model.BloggerWebsites[0].Website);` thrice, change the index and check if that solves your problem.

Comment: @VimalStan I'm afraid that did not work

Comment: what you are looking at is a nested viewmodel.you may need to create a separate viewmodel for person and nest it inside BloggerViewModel

Comment: @CodeIgnoto How can I pass both models to the view if I have 2 different models?

Comment: have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417564/can-you-use-nested-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc3

Answer (score 0):

You must use editors to handle the bindings to your nested model properties, a good example on how to do it can be found [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/).